# VBA Excel won't connect to Access DB on another computer

Tags: vba, ms-access

A colleague of mine is trying to use an excel tool that pulls data from an access database. The tool works perfectly on my computer but he is having the issue that the tool is unable to connect with the Access database.

I've tried solving the problem by checking that the excel options are correct i.e. making sure macros are enabled etc. but I'm still getting the problem.

The problem must be something in my colleagues settings that hasn't been configured because the tool works without any issues for me. Here are some of the parts of the code that read the Access DB:

```
Public Const pActuarialPWD = "password2"
Public Const QuoteDB = "N:\DWH\Commercial Ins\Fleet\Databases\Quote DB.accdb" 

    If bDBOpen = False Then
        'Connect to database
        If openQuotedb() = False Then
            MsgBox "Connection to database failed - contact Actuarial"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If


Function openQuotedb()

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    openQuotedb = False
        Set db = OpenDatabase(QuoteDB, False, False, "MS Access;PWD=" & pActuarialPWD)
    openQuotedb = True

    Exit Function

ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox "Couldn't connect to database. Please contact actuarial. Tool should not be used, as quote information will be lost", vbCritical

End Function
```

I've stepped through the program both in my computer and my colleagues a number of times and I can't see what the problem is. When I step past the line of code "db = ..." on my colleagues PC and hover over db it reads "db = Nothing" whereas on mine it successfully connects to the database.

Have you any ideas what might be going wrong here. It just seems exces is not setup properly to connect to Access on my colleagues PC.

The only thing I can think of is that I am using Excel 2013 and my colleague is on 2010.

Comment: Your problem is probably here: N:\ Is that a maped drive? On both computers is maped the same? Same letter and all?

Comment: @Blenikos +1 in any case it's safer to use the full path

Comment: HI Benikos, that's not the issue. The N drive is the same on both computers. I had my colleague try the tool on Office 2013 and it worked. I'm not sure why it didn't work on the 2010 version. Thanks

Comment: The only thing I can imagine happening is having different vba references between the two excel versions. Check the references in the vba editor. I have used the remote database connection a lot and I have never ecountered an error with it.

Comment: Curious, what was the error received? In your ErrorHandler, you should be raising actual error(`MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description`) and not just the custom message of *Couldn't connect to database*.

Answer (score 0):

The function below have saved me a lot of trouble. I don't know if it will solve your problem but in general will help.

I have tested it in many applications and with a variety of changes and variables and it worked every time and has never failed me. Maybe will help you.

```
Public Function db_connect(Optional sel_db As Variant = "", Optional pass_be As Variant = ";PWD=<password>") As DAO.Database
        Dim db As DAO.Database

        If sel_db = "" Then
            sel_db = "<database_path>"
        End If

    On Error GoTo db_locked:
                Set db = DBEngine.OpenDatabase(sel_db, True, False, pass_be)
                GoTo DBclose:
    db_locked:
                Sleep 100
                Set db = DB_Connection.db_connect(sel_db, pass_be)
    DBclose:
            Set db_connect = db
    End Function
```

To call the function just do:

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Set pers = DB_Connection.db_connect("full_path or your path with the N drive mapped", ";PWD=<db_password>")
```

**WARNING-DISCLAIMER!!!**
Be careful. The function has a waiting mechanism and tries to connect without never stoping. If you have wrong parameters or the database doesn't exist then it will stuck in an infinite loop. I never bothered to fix it because I knew the problem and avoid it. However, you can make improvements if you want.